# CSS: Tree structure with sibling divs, how to mark only sub-elements with CSS?

Tags: css

A tree structure is simulated with a sequence of sibling divs with varying left indent:

```
.l2 { padding-left: 1em; }
.l3 { padding-left: 2em; }
...

<div class="a"><div class="l1">A1</div></div>
<div class="a"><div class="l2">A2</div></div>
...
```

Using just CSS, is it possible to mark only siblings with lower level than the hovered item, but not those beyond the next item of the same level?

The snippet below illustrates the idea, but over-selects beyond the current nesting level. Couldn't figure out how to not select items that have an item of the same level as the hovered item closer than the one being hovered that is not being hovered over.

Explicitly:

- Hover over A1 should light up the border for all items marked A, but not B.
- Hover over second A2 should light up only the border of items A3, but not B.
- Hover over B1 lights up borders for B2 and B3.
- Hover over B2 lights up the border of B3, and so on.

Is this possible with CSS only? Modern CSS is just fine, no backward compatibility needed.

Note that no nested structure is possible as this is part of a rather large virtual list and it is not known in advance how many sub-levels there are, so the only solution is to render the sibling divs and mark their indent. The actual implementation has many more levels, but it's not a problem to generate appropriate CSS selector combinations if a solution exits.

Also no js is allowed; only CSS if possible.

```css
* { 
font-family: sans-serif;
border-left: 1px solid transparent; 
--l1-border: 1px solid purple; 
--l2-border: 1px solid blue;
}

.a { width: 150px; padding: 0 3px; }
.a:hover { background-color: #eee; }

.a:has(.l1):has(+ .a .l2):hover ~ .a .l2 {
  border-left: var(--l1-border);
}
.a:has(.l1):has(+ .a .l2):hover ~ .a .l3 {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 2em;
  border-left: var(--l1-border);
}

.a:has(.l2):has(+ .a .l3):hover ~ .a .l3 {
  border-left: var(--l2-border);
}

.l2 { padding-left: 1em; }
.l3 { padding-left: 1em; margin-left: 1em; }
```

```html
<div class="a"><div class="l1">A1</div></div>
<div class="a"><div class="l2">A2</div></div>
<div class="a"><div class="l2">A2</div></div>
<div class="a"><div class="l3">A3</div></div>
<div class="a"><div class="l3">A3</div></div>
<div class="a"><div class="l2">A2</div></div>
<div class="a"><div class="l1">B1</div></div>
<div class="a"><div class="l2">B2</div></div>
<div class="a"><div class="l3">B3</div></div>
```

Comment: Can you add/remove classes in HTML?

Comment: If you mean during rendering, yes, adding classes, css vars and even extra elements is okay.

Comment: For example all your div's have class .a. Can you change it so that it's .a for A elements and .b for B elements?

Comment: The snippet is only a simplification. The real structure would be more jagged: A3 could be followed by A4, then A5 then again A2 then A3, A4, A4, A5, A6, ... So we'd have to somehow mark each parent and its children with its class, and then recursively for inner structure again. And considering there could be millions of items and hundreds of levels deep, CSS seems like the only general solution.

Comment: Sorry, just want to double check. Are you sure a nested structure is not an option? It would solve your problem easily. Can you tell a bit more about how you render this tree? Do you retrieve it from database?

Comment: It's a virtual scroll, pages coming in as user scrolls. Say page size is 2 and we display 3 items: then we'd initially load data for pages 1 and 2 ({A1, A2}, {A2, A3}) and render `<div>A1<div>A2</div><div>A2<div>A3</div></div></div>`. Then on scroll we'd get {A3,A2}, so now we need to figure out how to change the structure to insert that page. Then after evicting page 1 we'd have to change the structure again. One can jump to page 100 without rendering previous 99 pages; what if that page starts with an item at level 600? Even at cutoff depth 20, we'd need 20 opening divs to make it valid.

Comment: Use a tree like structure (e.g. nested ul) for tree like data.

Comment: If you will have 100500 levels, do you want to write for each `.a:has(.l(n)) ~ a`... ? It looks like nonsense. I suggest you change the structure of the output, for example - nested lists.

Comment: @imhvost, any hierarchical display will have a cutoff level after which it doesn't make sense to indent. Applies to flat and nested elements equally. I found it hard to follow after ~15. Visual highlight improves orientation for hierarchies with many levels; hence this question. AFAIK, all virtual tree displays (loaded on demand) are structured with sibling elements like this (e.g. vscode file tree). Suggest you think it through; if you come up with a novel solution for lists with millions of elements@1000 levels deep, blog about it and link from a comment here.

Comment: @Mr.Curious you might as well copy the css from those virtual tree displays.

Comment: @SalmanA The purpose of asking the question is to satisfy one's curiosity and learn something new from those who are more knowledgeable and willing to engage in the intellectual challenge.

Comment: @Mr.Curious agreed, and I've given you a humble suggestion: adjust the markup. Similar questions have been asked dozens of times and the solution is almost always the same: start with complicated CSS for one item, then use SAAS to create copies of that rules for _n_ items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting task! Are you happy with your current approach in which you manually specify styles for each level? So far I have come up with an idea to add one more hover that targets next siblings of the same level and removes the border for all elements after them. Let me know what you think about this and maybe I will be able to find another solution.

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-left: 1px solid transparent;
  --l1-border: 1px solid purple;
  --l2-border: 1px solid blue;
}

.a {
  width: 150px;
  padding: 0 3px;
}

.a:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.a:has(.l1):has(+ .a .l2):hover~.a .l2 {
  border-left: var(--l1-border);
}

.a:has(.l1):has(+ .a .l2):hover~.a .l3 {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 2em;
  border-left: var(--l1-border);
}

.a:has(.l1):has(+ .a .l2):hover~.a:has(.l1)~.a * {
  border-left: none;
}

.a:has(.l2):has(+ .a .l3):hover~.a .l3 {
  border-left: var(--l2-border);
}

.a:has(.l2):has(+ .a .l3):hover~.a:has(.l2)~.a * {
  border-left: none;
}

.l2 {
  padding-left: 1em;
}

.l3 {
  padding-left: 1em;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="l1">A1</div>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <div class="l2">A2</div>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <div class="l2">A2</div>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <div class="l3">A3</div>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <div class="l3">A3</div>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <div class="l2">A2</div>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <div class="l1">B1</div>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <div class="l2">B2</div>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <div class="l3">B3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for coming up with this! Didn't think of chaining the general sibling combinators this way to express "nearer previous sibling" idiom. Knowing this, we can probably further optimize by writing selectors as "those preceded by hovered higher level but not preceded by same level as hovered that is preceded with hovered level." :-). Accepting the answer with thanks for the quick reaction. If you think of the more elegant solution, please update.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with combinations of :not and :has by setting the border for all those following the hovered element and then unsetting it for those at a 'higher' level or following one at a higher level further down.

```html
<style>
  * {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    border-left: 1px solid transparent;
    --l1-border: 1px solid purple;
    --l2-border: 1px solid blue;
  }
  
  .a {
    width: 150px;
    padding: 0 3px;
  }
  
  .a:hover {
    background-color: #eee;
  }
  
  .l2 {
    padding-left: 1em;
  }
  
  .l3 {
    padding-left: 1em;
    margin-left: 1em;
  }
  
  .a:has(.l1:hover)~.a:not(:has(.l1)) {
    rbackground: lime;
    border-left: var(--l1-border);
  }
  
  .a:has(.l1:hover)~.a:has(.l1)~* {
    rbackground: transparent;
    border-left: none;
  }
  
  .a:has(.l2:hover)~.a:not(:has(.l2)) {
    border-left: var(--l2-border);
  }
  
  .a:has(.l2:hover)~.a:has(.l1),
  .a:has(.l2:hover)~.a:has(.l1)~*,
  .a:has(.l2:hover)~.a:has(.l2)~* {
    border-left: none;
  }
</style>
<div class="a">
  <div class="l1">A1</div>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <div class="l2">A2</div>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <div class="l2">A2</div>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <div class="l3">A3</div>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <div class="l3">A3</div>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <div class="l2">A2</div>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <div class="l1">B1</div>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <div class="l2">B2</div>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <div class="l3">B3</div>
</div>
```

But it rapidly has the need to generate long selectors and an upper bound of the number of levels would need to be known as currently in CSS it is not possible to use variables or calculations in selectors.

i.e. it is likely to be impractical in a real-life situation.

A fun exercise but I don't recommend it's use in reality!